# Strange behaviour with positive lookahead regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

Look at this regexp:

```
console.log(/^a(?=b)$/.test('ab'));
```

I have tried it on an online tool. This tool says my 'ab' string matches.
But it displays false in javascript.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: [It does not match anywhere](https://regex101.com/r/vX1GrJ/1). You can't expect any text after the end of string. It is just the same as `$a` like regexps.

Answer (score 1):

A lookahead does not consume anything, so the `$` won't match because there's still the `b` left.
You can see it if you omit the `$`:

```js
console.log(/^a(?=b)/.test('ab'));
```

---

In more detail you ask your engine the following questions:

1. Does my expression start at the beginning of the string (`^`)? - *Yes it does.*
2. Is there an `a` coming? - *Yes there is.*
3. Is immediately after the `a` a `b` lurking around the corner? - *Yes there is.*
4. Is this the end of the string? - *No it's not, the `b` is still round the corner, my poor boy!*

So the engine cannot report a match and is left crying on the floor because her behaviour was called strange in the first place where she made everything correct.